# XML word document to .doc in Java

Tags: java, xml, ms-word

I have an xml word document (I had a word document (.doc) that I saved as xml word document (.xml) throught Word)

So I have this xml file. I can edit it as I want and I can open it with Word.

I just want to save this xml file back to the .doc file using Java.
I don't think I have to download the POI API.
But I can't figure out how to convert my xml word file back to the .doc file with Java.

Any pointers would be great !

Thanks !

Comment: What's wrong with using POI ? It will do exactly what you want, quite easily if I recall correctly.

Comment: Do you want to convert it to a legacy binary .doc, or a docx file?

Comment: I don't really care. I can rename my xml file to myxmlfile.doc and Word can open it. But I can't send it to my webmail because he detected a problem with the .doc. I assume it's because the header doesn't feet to the .doc header. So I just want to convert my xml to .doc or .docx with good header.